# Is this question I posted on Super User more appropriate for the Graphic Design SE site?

Tags: discussion

Long time reader, not a heavy participant with a solid rep across a few different Stack Exchange sites and have a question for *this* site: Is [this specific Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1702674/167207) I posted a day or so ago more appropriate for the Graphic Design SE site?

In a nutshell the question title is “Is it possible to simplify the paths of an EPS via the command line using Ghostscript?” and I am basically looking to see if there is a command line option that would simplify paths in an EPS via Ghostscript within the context of a one-line EPS to PDF conversation process.

I’m not confident it would work here… But at the same time I think the audience for Potrace and Ghostscript questions on Super User is fairly narrow. Meaning not as many eyes over there on Super User would know how to answer such a question.

What does the community here think? Should I close the Super User question and migrate it here?

Comment: I don't know that the audience here would be any greater than SuperUser's audience. Ghostscript isn't a widely common GD tool. That being posted, I don't think it's *entirely* off-topic here. But that's just my opinion - I'm no mod or anything.

Comment: I dont think there are all that many ghost script users around here. In general using ghostscript is a programming related task so id say it would fit better on stackoverflow where number of users that i expect to answer this is 3.

Comment: I know [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo) has an optimize function that can drastically reduce the number of points in an SVG path without loss of info. If you're not afraid to get your hands dirty with programming, you could have a look at their logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to whether the question is on topic: I wouldn't close it if you asked it on the main site. It's at least tangentially related to graphic design.

However, I don't think you'd get a lot of useful answers. As others have said in the comments: there's not a lot of ghostscript users in the graphic design community.

I think there's two places where this question would probably get more response:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghostscript?tab=Newest). At the core, this is a *programming* question. So it would be apt to ask programmers rather than designers. Even the official documentation refers to Stack Overflow.
- Artifex, the ghostscript developers. They have a [Discord](https://discord.com/invite/H9GXKwyPvY) and [IRC](https://web.libera.chat/#ghostscript). And of course a general [contact page](https://artifex.com/contact/).